# Изменить текст на TextVie на не активном табе(фрагменте)

Tags: android-fragment, fragment-manager

У меня приложение с Navigation Drawer которое имеет 6 фрагментов. Первый фрагмент называется MainFragment. MainFragment в свою очередь имеет 4 фрагмента(таба). Они называются FragmentOne(COMMON), FragmentTwo(Battery), FragmentThree(Internal), FragmentFour(Internal).В MainActivity запускается AsyncTask(MyTask) который меняет текст в текущем фрагменте OneFragment(Common) и на не активном фрагменте ThirdFragment(Internal). Мой вопрос: этот AsyncTask не может изменить текст на TextView на этих табах(Common and Internal). Как это сделать? Что я делал: если сделать активным таб Common(FragmentOne) TabLayout.getTabAt(0).select() то изменение текста на TextView на Common(FragmentOne) работает. Если переключиться на третий таб Internal(FragmentThree) TabLayout.getTabAt(2).select() то срабатывает exception. Как изменить текст TextView на не активном фрагменте. Исходный код прилагается. Основные фрагменты: MainActivity MainFragment FragmentFirst FragmentSecond .... FragmentSix.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    while (!isCancelled()) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    Log.d(TAG, "MainFragment do try");

    try {
        //tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select(); textV1.setText не работает когда tab(0) не активен

        TextView textV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextName2);
        textV1.setText("InternalMemory");

        TextView textV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textParam6);
        textV2.setText("All: "+bytesToHuman(getTotalInternalSpace()));

        TextView textV3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textParam7);
        textV3.setText("Path: "+getInternalMemoryPath());

        TextView textV4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textParam9);
        textV4.setText("Free: "+bytesToHuman(getAvailableInternalSpaceSize()));

        int t4 = (int) Math.ceil(((getAvailableInternalSpaceSize()*100)/getTotalInternalSpace()));
        TextView textV5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textParam8);
        textV5.setText(String.format("%d ",t4) + "% ");

        ProgressBar textV6 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        textV6.setProgress(t4);
        if (t4<=20) {
            textV6.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        } else if ((t4>20) && (t4<=40)){
            textV6.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.MAGENTA, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        } else if ((t4>40) && (t4<=60)){
            textV6.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        } else if ((t4>60) && (t4<=80)){
            textV6.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        } else if ((t4>80) && (t4<=90)){
            textV6.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        } else if ((t4>90) && (t4<=100)){
            textV6.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        } else textV6.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            Log.d(TAG, "MainFragment do internalMemoryInfo");


        //tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();ThreeFragment.showText не работает когда tab(2) не активен

        ThreeFragment.showText(textV2.getText() + "\n" +
                               textV3.getText() + "\n" +
                               textV4.getText() + "\n" +
                               "Percent: " + textV5.getText());

        Log.d(TAG, "MainFragment posle internalMemoryInfo");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MainFragment in Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите или скажите что не так.

Comment: Hello. Здесь есть кто нибудь?

Answer (score -1):

В общем, пришлось перенести `MyTask` из `MainActivity` в `MainFragment`

Comment: Ну на русском надо отвечать...